# Repeat an array, but everytime with different attributes of the font

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
<body>

<p id="demo"></p>
 <script>
   var week = ["Maandag", "Dinsdag", "Woensdag", "Donderdag", "Vrijdag", "Zaterdag", "Zondag"];
   var text = "";
   var i;
      for (i = 0; i < week.length; i++) {
      text += week[i] + "<br>";
      }

     document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;
</script>
</body>
```

I currently have this, and it display like

- monday
- theusday
- wednesday
- etc.

And it does it just once. It should repeat is 6 times, but every time it should expand the FONT its size by one but the text content itself should stay the same.

Comment: Why it should repeat 6 times ? and what you are doing to change the font size ?

Comment: It's an exercise but i'm wondering how i can do this. Changing the fontsize with <h1>, <h2>, <h3>, <h4>, <h5> and <h6>

Comment: Why not try something like this - http://plnkr.co/edit/uFjwkY8v1i529AKXIYDb?p=preview

Comment: btw you have seven items and header tag takes from 1 to 6 only, how about this you thought to manage ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a cycle to do that:

```
<body>

<p id="demo"></p>
 <script>
   var week = ["Maandag", "Dinsdag", "Woensdag", "Donderdag", "Vrijdag", "Zaterdag", "Zondag"];
   var text = "";
   var i;
      for (var j = 1; j <= 6; j++) {
          text += "<h" + j + ">";
          for (i = 0; i < week.length; i++) {
              text += week[i] + "<br>";
          }
          text += "<h" + j + ">";
      }

     document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;
</script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to wrap your loop in another one for the font sizes.

```js
var weeks = ["Maandag", "Dinsdag", "Woensdag", "Donderdag", "Vrijdag", "Zaterdag", "Zondag"];
var text = "";

for (let headerSize = 1; headerSize < 7; headerSize++) {
  text += `(Heading size: ${headerSize})`;
  text += weeks.map(week => `<h${headerSize}>${week}</h${headerSize}>`).join('\n');
}

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;
```

```html
<div id="demo"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also increment the style `font-size` like this..

```js
var week = ["Maandag", "Dinsdag", "Woensdag", "Donderdag", "Vrijdag", "Zaterdag", "Zondag"];
var fontSize = 12;

for (var count = 0; count < 6; count++ ) {
  var text = "";
  var div = document.createElement('div');
  div.className = "days";
  div.style= "font-size:" + (fontSize + count + 1).toString() + "px;";
  for (var i = 0; i < week.length; i++) {
   text += week[i] + "<br>";
  }
  div.innerHTML = text;
  document.getElementById("demo").appendChild(div);
}
```

```css
div.days {
  padding-top:10px;
}
```

```html
<p id="demo"></p>
```